# Container killed by YARN for exceeding memory limits for saveAstable

Tags: dataframe, pyspark, hadoop-yarn

I have a huge dataframe (df), which after doing some process and manipulation on it, I want to save it as a table.

```
df.write.partitionBy('p1', 'p2', 'p3', 'p4').format("parquet").saveAsTable('table_name')
```

I get this error:

```
Container killed by YARN for exceeding memory limits. 36.4 GB of 36 GB physical memory used.
```

And there are too many of this message:

```
19/10/17 00:52:10 WARN org.apache.spark.scheduler.TaskSetManager: Lost task 190.3 in stage 0.0 (
```

And no matter how much I increase the --executor-memory I still get the same error with different numbers. How can I resolve this issue?

Comment: Hey Alan, can you provide us some more information like what all params are you passing to execute the Spark job, the cluster size and the total number of cores available ?

Comment: NUM_EXECUTOR_TASKS="3"
DRIVER_MEMORY="4g"
EXECUTOR_MEMORY="16g"
DRIVER_MEMORY_OVERHEAD="1g"
MAX_CORES="100"
MESOS_COARSE="true"
NUM_EXECUTOR_CORES="6"
NUM_CPUS="2"

Comment: the cluster is auto-scalable and as I mentioned I increased the executor to 32g again it complained about memory. No matter how much (executor) memory is assigned it asks for more.

Comment: Can you please give the following params to the Spark-Submit 
`--driver-memory 4g`
`--conf spark.executor.memoryOverhead=2048 `
`--conf spark.driver.memoryOverhead=2048 `
`--conf spark.sql.shuffle.partitions=100 `
`--conf spark.shuffle.consolidateFiles=true `
`--conf spark.dynamicAllocation.enabled=true `
`--conf spark.dynamicAllocation.minExecutors=0 `
`--conf spark.dynamicAllocation.maxExecutors=10 `
`--conf spark.dynamicAllocation.executorIdleTimeout=60s `
`--conf spark.dynamicAllocation.cachedExecutorIdleTimeout=60s`

Comment: Also dont provide the `num-executor, executor-memory, max-cores, num-executor-core, num-cpus` considering the cluster being auto scalable and as we are passing dynamic allocation via Spark-Submit

Comment: I get the same errors and this error: ERROR org.apache.spark.network.server.TransportRequestHandler: Error while invoking RpcHandler#receive() for one-way message.
org.apache.spark.rpc.RpcEnvStoppedException: RpcEnv already stopped.